# Clickable image with textview in a row

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout

i want to dynamically add images and textviews from database (blue on the picture). I also want it to be clickable, and that it could pass it's Id or something to the next activity. I thought of listview, but eclipse says it shouldn't be in a scrollview. So I tried creating linear layout, and inside it I tried to put another linear layouts (different orientation) containing image and textview (so like one linear layout per row). I'm not sure if I did it ok, but it only displays first image and last textview, so i guess it's not the right way.

Here's the layout image:
http://pbrd.co/R0JVKs

Here's how I add the views:

```
//architekti
              llArchitekti = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.architekt_layout);
              LinearLayout llArchitekt;
              ImageView arch_obr;
              TextView tvArchitekt;
              int i = 0;
              for(String architekt : architekti){
                  arch_obr = new ImageView(ObjectInfo.this);
                  if(architekti_obrazky.size()>i && architekti_obrazky.get(i)!="no_image"){
                      arch_obr.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/images/thumb/obr_"+architekti_obrazky.get(i)+"_1.jpg"));
                  }else{
                      arch_obr.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/images/thumb/no_image.jpg"));
                  }
                  arch_obr.setPadding(8, 8, 20, 8);
                  arch_obr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 150 , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                  //here starts the adding part
                  llArchitekt = new LinearLayout(ObjectInfo.this);
                  llArchitekt.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                  llArchitekt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                  tvArchitekt = new TextView(ObjectInfo.this);
                  tvArchitekt.setText(architekt);
                  tvArchitekt.setClickable(true);
                  tvArchitekt.setTextSize(22);
                  tvArchitekt.setPadding(8, 8, 20, 8);
                  tvArchitekt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                  llArchitekt.addView(arch_obr);
                  llArchitekt.addView(tvArchitekt);
                  llArchitekti.addView(llArchitekt);
                  i++;
              }
```

llArchitekt should be linear layout for each row, llArchitekti should be the linear layout that I add rows to.

llArchitekt - vertical
llArchitekti - horizontal

Also I'm not sure if it's possible to get some ID (ideally the one from database) from it on click.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ListView with Custom Adapter. There are many tutorials on the web:

[Custom Listview Tutorial](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)